# How to set img's src to a img from url. NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

Using the [image-picker module](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker) I grab an image successfully,

URL: `/storage/emulated/0/Screenshots/Screenshot_20180624-232124.png`
Now that I have an src I tried to apply it.

```
//Url is the url above^
url = url.substring(0,url.length-4);//removes the .png or .jpg from url.
page.getViewById(`myImg`).src = `res:/${url}`;
```

Which doesn't apply it. I just get the error: [pasted at pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cdXNd2J6)

and image doesnt change.

What am i doing wrong? I have looked at the docs on both the module and the NS docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use the image path you get from `image-picker` module by setting it as url.

`<Image src={{url}}></Image>` and `url="/storage/emulated/0/Screenshots/Screenshot_20180624-232124.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Welp I got some help from someone else.
by adding:

```
const imageSourceModule = require(`tns-core-modules/image-source`);
let img = imageSourceModule.fromFile(url);
page.getViewById(`myImg`).imageSource = img;
```

I didn't know about the `imageSource` property seeing as the docs use `src`